# Xcode "iPhone Simulator" not showing up in Audio Midi Setup > Midi Network Setup

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, midi

I am building an iPad Midi App and therefore need to connect to midi devices while running the App in the simulator. The following are the basic instructions:

Apple Mac OSX Simulator (iPhone or iPad)

1. Open Audio Midi Setup on OSX. Make sure MIDI window is checked (Window Menu->Show MIDI Window
2. Double click on Network (in MIDI Studio)
3. If Session box is empty click + and create a session - default is Session1
4. Run the xcode project and "iPhone Simulator" should appear in the Directory box.
5. Click Connect - this moves over to the Session box as a participant.

The problem is "iPhone Simulator" has only shown up twice in the last 6 months and has gone again after the OSX 10.11.2 upgrade a few days ago. I have tried rebooting, changing the startup order of all the Apps involved all without luck. Finally filed a radar with Apple.

So I was wondering if anyone knows a trick to get this to catch? It has caught twice before but I have been unable to reproduce it.

Comment: Apple got back to me ... "Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:

MIDI Networking between OS X and the Sim is not supported at this time."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had this issue before also; this seemed to do the trick for me:

> 1. Check to make sure you don't have duplicates of the CoreMIDI.Framework in your project.     *If present remove the
>      reference to the duplicate `CoreMIDI.Framework` <sub>(highlight, tap delete)</sub>
> 2. `Product > Clean`
> 3. Run the iOS Simulator

You should now see the iPhone Simulator in Session 1.

Comment: Tried this. Build a test project removed duplicated CoreMidi.Frameworks without luck alas. Rebooted, rescanned midi ... all chicken blood I could think off. Thanks for tip regardless!

Comment: It's more a matter of the simulator being able to talk to the OS X MIDI interface, so rebooting is more or less pointless. In the MIDI Network Setup also make sure you have Session 1 checked on, and Session Enabled checked on. Also try setting "Who may connect to me" to "Anyone". In the debug window when you are trying it what messages are appearing? it might help to post the transcript here.

Comment: All tried many times. Apple did get back me alas, see there response above. I'm using Music IO while debugging on the iPad, it will have todo. Thanks again.

Comment: @FlimFlamVir: Apple may not officially support it, although it's still possible. If you want I'll zip up a project that works on my system and you can give it a try... let me know.

Comment: Hell, yes! I have spent so much time on Midi connectivity tearing my hair out. Now working on a latency issue to an old Synth. I haven't given up yet! Many Thanks

Comment: @FlimFlamVir: [Project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/u2s6dg6mitgwk4q/MidiNotes-master.dmg?dl=0), [Session](https://www.dropbox.com/s/waeoaav3netkwuj/Session.png?dl=0), [Simulator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfvhblehrutuz1m/Simulator.png?dl=0), Let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Wow. This is interesting. Wasn't working on the sym after the first build, so messed around a bit and noticed the Target was set to iOS 4.2, testing the coreMidi first release version I'm thinking. So set it 9.2 and ran on the sym and hey presto "iPhone Simulator" - thar she blows! I'm using MIKMidi framework podfile, I've found a bug in there that I'm guessing he won't fix so was considering going back to just including the source while I sort this out. So many thanks for this, I also get some more midi code to paw over. Wish I could give you some bounty :)

Comment: You're welcome! The MIDINotes project was developed in 2011 which might be why it had the target set on iOS 4.2. Some things might need to be updated as things often change, although the basics are there which should help moving forward. I haven't tried MIKMidi, but you can always ask another question on here if you can't get it sorted it out. Always happy to help, and I'm glad that we got this worked out — cheers! :)

Comment: One final update. I went back and ripped out the MIKMIDI podfile from my test project and just dumped the source in the project. It worked the first time.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have this code before connecting to a MIDI device.

**Objective-C:**

```
#import <CoreMIDI/MIDINetworkSession.h>

MIDINetworkSession* session = [MIDINetworkSession defaultSession];
session.enabled = YES;
session.connectionPolicy = MIDINetworkConnectionPolicy_Anyone;
```

**Swift:**

```
let session = MIDINetworkSession.default()
session.isEnabled = true
session.connectionPolicy = MIDINetworkConnectionPolicy.anyone
```

Below is a good resource as well.

> http://goodliffe.blogspot.ca/2011/01/more-ios-midi-using-networked-midi.html

Comment: <code>        MIDINetworkSession.defaultSession().enabled = true <BR>
        MIDINetworkSession.defaultSession().connectionPolicy = MIDINetworkConnectionPolicy.Anyone
<code>

Comment: yes and formatting got away from me and the timer ran out on the comment ... oh hum! Your's is the most complete answer.

Comment: This answer did it for me. Set enabled to YES and connectionPolicy to Anyone.

Answer (score 2):

After much messing around the following seems to the situation here:

1) If you manage to link in CoreMidi.framework more than once you will lose the "iPhone Simulator" per l'L'l's answer. 
2) If you use a Cocoa Pod which uses CoreMidi.Framework e.g. MIKMIDI you can lose the "iPhone Simulator". The only fix I found was to include the source or use a subproject.

Firstly Apple said:

"Engineering has provided the following feedback regarding this issue:

MIDI Networking between OS X and the Sim is not supported at this time."

Ho hum, a not going to fix! To further clarify this is OSX 10.11.2 and Xcode 7.2

Then they felt guilty and out of the blue send me this:

This is a courtesy email regarding Bug ID# 23875386.

Engineering has provided the following feedback and requested some additional information in order to further investigate this issue:

It sounds like you want to activate the network MIDI driver in the simulator so that it can communicate with the host environment.

Does this help (called from your app)?:

## import

...
[MIDINetworkSession defaultSession].enabled = YES;

This works in **ALL** situations!

Answer (score 2):

Confirmed on Mac OS 10.12.4:

Be sure to set the port for the host and the simulator to be different. They are both generally set to 5004 by default but will clash over the port if both are run at the same time.

Try changing your host session to port 5006.

Comment: Thank you for this! The port thing was the reason it wasn't working for me.